# How to ovveride method String valueOf

Tags: java, string

In my class I used standard method

```
public static String valueOf(Object obj) {
   return (obj == null) ? "null" : obj.toString();
}
```

How can I ovveride or reimplement this metod in my class that, return something like this:

```
public static String valueOf(Object obj) {
       return (obj == null) ? "" : obj.toString();
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't override it (you can't override any static method, and even if it wasn't static, `String` is a final class that can't be extended).

There's nothing stopping you from implementing it in your class as you wish, and using your implementation. However, you can't cause existing code to use your implementation.

Comment: Very help full. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make output of your object, you could just override `toString()` method of `Object` and call `System.out.println(obj)`

```
@Override
public String toString(){
   StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer();
   sb.append(...);
   sb.append(...);
   return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: Very help full. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Static methods cannot be overridden.

Additionally, you can't override a non-static method unless your class extends the class it's declared in. So even if this was non-static, you couldn't override it unless your class extends `String` (which it doesn't, and shouldn't, and can't anyway because `String` is final).

What you can do is create your own method, and call it instead of the built-in one.

Comment: Very help full. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

String is a final class. You can't extend it. Moreover this `valueOf` method is a static method which can't be overridden.

Comment: You can override it , but its actually overhidden rather !!

Comment: Very help full. Thanks